# Is there a clean separating definition between "STL" and "C++ Standard Library"?

Tags: c++, stl, std

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's this STL vs. “C++ Standard Library” fight all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-this-stl-vs-c-standard-library-fight-all-about)

I am very much used to the term **STL** ("Standard Template Library") and I catch myself often using it when I really mean the **C++ Standard Library**. So, since almost everything in the C++(-11) Standard Library is a template nowadays, I wonder: **Is there a definition what is STL and what is not, in the C++Standard-Lib?** Maybe containers, streams, algorithms, etc?

Or should I just stop using the term "STL", because it's the historic one that SGI (correct?) used for their lib years back? It will be difficult...

Comment: (Sorry, I marked the wrong duplicate)

Comment: Someone else marked it right, thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

STL has evolved into C++ Standard Library, it contained containers, iterators and algorithms but not streams. It is better not to use term "STL" it is the name of the old library.